# Too slow to load json result

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have one website regarding airport shipment.

http://vemployee.net/aircargo/

On the home page of the website, there is "Where do you want to Ship to ?" section where user will search origin & destination airport places. Both the sections have auto suggest functionality.

I have one javascript file in which near about 46,000 airport list are available in json format. Auto suggest call goes to this file to search origin & destination airport places.

e.g. this file contains a record in below format.
[{"ident":"00A","name":"Total Rf Heliport","iso_country":"US","iso_region":"US-PA","municipality":"Bensalem","iata_code":"","local_code":"00A"},{"ident":"00AK","name":"Lowell Field","iso_country":"US","iso_region":"US-AK","municipality":"Anchor Point","iata_code":"","local_code":"00AK"}]

& auto suggest code is below :

```
var source = $.getValues(SITEROOT+'/airport-code.js');
$(function () {
  $( "#origin_airport").autocomplete({ 
    source: function(request, response){
        var searchTerm = request.term.toLowerCase();
        var ret = [];
        $.each(source, function(i, airportItem){
            if (airportItem.municipality.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1 || airportItem.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) === 0 || airportItem.iso_country.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) === 0 || airportItem.iata_code.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) === 0 || airportItem.local_code.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) === 0)
         if(airportItem.type != 'closed')
                ret.push(airportItem.name+' , '+airportItem.municipality+' , '+airportItem.ident);
        });

        response(ret);
    },
    search: function() { $('#originloader').show(); },
    open: function() { $('#originloader').hide(); }
  });

 $( "#destination_airport").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        var searchTerm = request.term.toLowerCase();
        var ret = [];
        $.each(source, function(i, airportItem){
            if (airportItem.municipality.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1 || airportItem.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) === 0 || airportItem.iso_country.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) === 0 || airportItem.iata_code.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) === 0 || airportItem.local_code.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) === 0)

                if(airportItem.type != 'closed')
        ret.push(airportItem.name+' , '+airportItem.municipality+' , '+airportItem.ident);
        });

        response(ret);
    },
    search: function() { $('#dsloader').show(); },
    open: function() { $('#dsloader').hide(); }
  });
});
```

When I search for any airport from any search box it auto suggest the list then I select one of them after I remove the selected airport & again search for another airport from same search box then it takes too much amount of time to load. On chrome & IE, website gets hanged for the same situation.

Can you please give me the solution?

Comment: With 46,000 airports you might be better off storing the data (and metadata) in a database. JSON files, unlike databases, cannot be indexed and complicated queries sometimes not possible.

Comment: Can't you use a database instead?

Comment: There are a lot of these lately... Json/Javascript/Ajax is not magic, it cannot make things just go faster